# VB.Net datatable.select not working with "like"

Tags: vb.net, datatable

This is driving me nuts!

I have a data table, lets call it `tbl` which I want to select rows dependent on a number of rules I have else where such as
`col_a > 'H00' and col_a < 'HZZ`

and

`col_b > '0000000000000' and col_b < 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'`

and

`col_b like '%0__'`

This then gives me an expression of something like:

`dim expression as string = "( col_a > 'H00' and col_a < 'HZZ ) and ( col_b > '0000000000000' and col_b < 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' ) and col_b like '%0__'"`

The first two work perfectly, but when I introduce the "like" is returns zero rows.

```
Dim foundfaults As DataRow()
foundfaults = baseTable.Select(expression)
```

If I just use `dim expression as string = "( col_a > 'H00' and col_a < 'HZZ ) and ( col_b > '0000000000000' and col_b < 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ' )`  I get data selected, but if I include the "like" there are zero rows.

Why doesn't it like the "like"?

Comment: If it didn't like `LIKE` then an exception would be thrown. Since that is not the case, it clearly does like `LIKE`. You're ignoring the obvious: if no rows are returned then no rows match the specified criteria. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You haven't provided any example inputs or expected outputs for us to have any clue why your expectations are wrong.

Comment: My guess is that you haven't actually bothered to read the documentation and you think that an underscore is a wildcard that represents a single character. It's not. Only `*` and `%` are valid wildcards. They both represent multiple characters and they are both only valid at the beginning and end of a value. Only a small subset of valid SQL is supported in such contexts what you seem to want is not included. This is why you should ALWAYS read the documentation, especially before posting a question here.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - sorry to burst your bubble, but if I put exactly the same in as WHERE in an sql statement, it returns rows so there *are* rows matching, and in the controlled environment in which I'm testing it the base table *only* contains data that matches. In sql "like" queries _ and % are the wildcards

Comment: Look for typos in your like clause. Use debugger to get the exact value of your sql statement and run it it SSMS to see if there are any syntax errors

Comment: @Vasya - the exact same criteria work in a standard sql query so I know there's no typos. It's not efficient to re-query the database every time I need to loop through the search strings, so I've loaded the data into a table and using .select to pick the rows from that table. It's only the "like" bit that causes the problem.

Comment: *"In sql "like" queries _ and % are the wildcards"*. The `DataTable.Select` method doesn't support everything in the SQL standard, as I already told you. I guess you know better though. It must not be working the way you expect for some other, completely unrelated reason. Good luck with that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think I misunderstood what you originally said. My apologies. Thanks for clarifying.  That restriction makes it difficult to select based on  something like %X__ where I am checking for X and any two characters after it, rather than %X% which wouldn't work for what I need.  Thanks again; going to have to think about how this works now...

Comment: I'd still suggest reading the relevant documentation as there may still be a way to achieve what you want using character indexes. It would definitely be kludgier than using a single-character wildcard but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: Failing that, maybe a LINQ query is a better option. Doesn't VB have its own Like operator? Maybe that would do the job, although I'm not sure what it supports as I don't think I've ever used it.

Answer (score 0):

@jmcilhinne was correct in his assessment of the problem. I misunderstood his first post, to my detriment.

`Like` does not work with "_" as a wildcard.